# Reference request for the history of logic

Tags: reference-request, history-of-logic

I have lately been interested in the history of logic, specifically, propositional logic and first-order logic. I want to know how those logical systems were first thought of. Can anyone give me some references?

Comment: Kneale & Kneale, [The development of logic](https://archive.org/details/developmentoflog0000knea/page/n6/mode/1up) and Haaparanta, [The development of Modern Logic](https://www.amazon.com/Development-Modern-Logic-Leila-Haaparanta/dp/0195137310)

Comment: See [Wikipedia, History of logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_logic) and [SEP, The Emergence of First-Order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-firstorder-emergence/). Both have long lists of references for further reading.